# My react typescript app always show a Firebase Welcome screen

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, hosting

I am implementing an application with react typecript.

I try to upload my application to Firebase hosting but a "Welcome to Firebase Hosting" screen always appears. The problem I have is that now when I run `npm run build` locally it doesn't generate my application anymore, it always generates the index.html with the Firebase screen.

How could I fix this problem?

Comment: Could you share sample code, your `package.json` and maybe some other relevant resource in this?